# rewrite file instead of recreating a file

Tags: java, file, url-rewriting

I have the following piece of code which allows me to recreate a file holding updated data. Even though I used the "StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING" option to overwrite the old file I was getting an error saying that the file already exists and it wouldn't write on top of it!

```
File filename = new File("data.txt");
public void writeToFile(char[] data){
    filename.delete();
    Files.write(filename.toPath(), data, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
}
```

Is it possible instead of deleting and recreating the same file over and over to edit the initial file's data?

Thank you

EDIT1: It seems like it was a mistake of mine. Together with "StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING" I have included "StandardOpenOption.CREEATE_NEW".
This is because I want the file to be created in case it doesn't already exist! How is it possible to first try to edit it and if it doesnt exist create a new one?

Sorry for my initial mistake

Comment: What language are you using

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING truncates the file content when you open it, so you just have to remove the call to .delete() method.

Comment: I am using java @Dason

Comment: @Max This exactly what I did in the first place but whet it tried to write and the file already existed I was getting an error: java.io.IOException: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: data.txt

Comment: That's unexpected because it apparently goes against what's written in the documentation. What JDK version are you on?

Comment: @Max I am on version 7. Thanks for helping but I found the solution (as posted underneath) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go on this one (which worked for me) is creating a `try{}catch{}` block and within the "try" try to edit the file and if it fails because it doesn't exist create a new file in the "catch".

Answer (score 0):

Look at the JavaDoc of the write method in the Files class, it says: "By default the method creates a new file or overwrites an existing file", so it seems that all you need to do is:

```
File filename = new File("data.txt");

public void writeToFile(char[] data) throws IOException {
    Files.write(filename.toPath(), data);
}
```